# Explanation of tac --before

Tags: coreutils, tac

> -b, --before
>
> The separator is attached to the beginning of the record that it
>   precedes in the file.

And I can't understand the following output:

```
$ echo -e "Hello\nNew\nWorld\n!" > file
$ tac file
!
World
New
Hello
$ tac -b file


!
World
NewHello
```

Why there is no newline between `New` and `Hello`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`tac` works with records and their separators, *attached*, by default after the corresponding record. This is somewhat counter-intuitive compared to other record-based tools (such as AWK) where separators are detached.

With `-b`, the records, with their newline attached, are as follows (in original order):

- `Hello`
- `\nNew`
- `\nWorld`
- `\n!`
- `\n`

Output in reverse, this becomes

```
\n\n!\nWorld\nNewHello
```

which corresponds to the output you see.

Without `-b`, the records, with their newline attached, are as follows:

- `Hello\n`
- `New\n`
- `World\n`
- `!\n`

Output in reverse, this becomes

```
!\nWorld\nNew\nHello\n
```

Answer (score 5):

That does look strange partly due `tac` works in somewhat counter-intuitive way as to me. Let's make use of clearly visible separators — commas.

What would I expect to see as the result of the following command:

```
% echo -ne 'A,B,C' | tac -s,
```

?

Well, I see it as there's A separated from B separated from C. Thus (I conclude) being printed in reverse, they should constitute `C,B,A`. Let's check. Alas, it prints differently instead:

```
% echo -ne 'A,B,C' | tac -s,
CB,A,
```

We can conclude `tac` sticks for original separators placement: `A` still has it afterwards, as well as `B` does, but `C` didn't have it and hence it's printed as is.

What happens if I run `tac` with `-b` this time?

```
% echo -ne 'A,B,C' | tac -bs,
,C,BA
```

Seemingly it works this way for `-b`: it's going through the input in backward direction till it finds a separator. As it's found it's printed:

`,`. Then it prints the text it skipped while searching:

`C`. Then the cycle repeats:

`,B`. As there're no separators left, just the remainder is printed:

`A`.

> Why there is no newline between New and Hello?

According to the explanation I've given above `New` would be on a new line because it was prefixed with new-line, but since `Hello` wasn't — it'd be printed as is.

Comment: Regarding your first part, it helps to understand `tac`’s counter-intuitive behaviour if you consider that its initial goal was to reverse text files, which end with a `\n`. The configurable separator does suggest that it can reverse records separated by arbitrary characters, in which case you don’t expect the text to end with a separator, but it doesn’t work that way :-(. Your explanation of `-b` is a fairly accurate description of coreutils’ implementation of `tac`; note however that `tac` always searches backwards (even without `-b`).

Comment: Indeed tac is always tac, even w/o `-b`